¿Existen riesgos al mostrar información en la URL al pasar información de una vista a otra? ASP.NET MVC C#
Estoy trabajando desde hace poco con asp.net mvc y aun sigo aprendiendo muchas cosas a medida que avanzo. Esta vez estoy realizando un proyecto para mostrar información sobre combos a travez de varias vistas donde el usuario debe escoger las opciones que se les va dando para llegar a un resultado.
Tengo una vista llamada edificios donde me muestra los edificios que existen y el usuario al darle click a uno de ellos lo redirije a una vista de lineas la cual solo le muestra las lineas del edificio escogido. Para ello lo que hago es pasar el id del edificio escogido por url y en el metodo de mi controlador recibir ese id y poder realizar la consulta de esas lineas de ese edificio.
Me funciona perfectamente, pero me fije que la info del id siempre se muestra en la url como en la siguiente imagen:

Pero me he estado preguntando sobre si esta parte no se deberia mostrar, o si es un dato sensible el cual se debiera encriptar o algo para no mostrarlo?
Mi pregunta es si ¿Mostrar asi la info es riesgoso y algo que no se debe hacer? Si, es asi ¿Como se encripta o oculta esa información?
Estuve buscando pero aun no he dado con una respuesta que aclare mis dudas. Alguien que sepa sobre esto que me de una mano explicandome y ayudamndome con este problema?
Este es mi codigo de mi vista:
<div class="row">
                @foreach (var edificio in Model)
                {
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 mt-4">
                        <div class="icon-box">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-building" style="color: #005486;"></i>
                            <h3><a href="@Url.Action("seccion_lines", "Home", new { idEdificio = edificio.IdEdificio })">@edificio.nave_edificio</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>

Y este es el metodo de mi controlador:
public ActionResult seccion_lines(int IdEdificio)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Seccion Lineas";

            try
            {
                using (_conexion)
                {
                    _conexion.AbrirConexion();

                    string nombreEdificio = ObtenerNombreEdificio(IdEdificio, _conexion);

                    SqlCommand cmd = _conexion.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SP_02"];
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Agregar parámetro al comando
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdEdificio", IdEdificio);

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    var lineas = new List<Lineas>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lineas.Add(new Lineas
                        {
                            IdLinea = (int)reader["IdLinea"],
                            lin_nombre = (string)reader["lin_nombre"]
                        });
                    }

                    reader.Close();  // Cerrar el SqlDataReader antes de cerrar la conexión
                    _conexion.CerrarConexion();

                    if (lineas.Count == 0)
                    {
                        TempData["WarningMessage"] = "Actualmente no existen lineas para el edificio seleccionado.";
                    }

                    ViewBag.NombreEdificio = nombreEdificio;

                    return View(lineas);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["WarningMessage"] = "Error al conectar con el servidor. Compruebe la conexión a internet o vuelva a intentarlo más tarde.";
                return View(new List<Lineas>());
            }
        }


Esta es una buena pregunta, pero muy dependiente de opiniones... en el [chat] seria mejor discutida. Mas alla de como pases los datos, la regla es simple, no se le cree nada de nada a lo que viene del front, y siempre se vuelve a validar todo...
